# Python to JavaScript with sum, map and lambda

Tags: javascript, python

I'm not familiar with Python, and I'm trying to convert a function to JavaScript, but I can't quite figure out what this line does:

```
maxnum = sum(map(lambda x: x[1], tsweights))
```

where `tsweights` = `[['5', 61], ['6', 61], ['7', 61], ... ]`.

I have no idea how this works and it would be great if someone could help out.

Full function: http://pastebin.com/PZqRAz0Z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with some hints.

`lambda x: x[1]` is just an anonymous function which does the same thing as this:

```
function foo(x) {
    return x[1];
}
```

`map()` is equivalent to [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). I think you can figure out what `sum()` does.

Relevant Python docs:

- [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda)
- [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)
- [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to this in JavaScript...

```
var tsweights = [['5', 61], ['6', 61], ['7', 61], ... ];
var maxnum = 0;
for (var i in tsweights)
{
    maxnum += tsweights[i][1];
}
```

Comment: Usefull, but in javascript you need to do `tsweights[tsweight][1]`. in this sample the var `tsweight` is the key, not value. it did help me though, plus one.

Comment: @MakuraYami Oops. My bad. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

That function can be rewritten like so:

```
sum = 0
for item in tsweights:
    sum += item[1]
```

If `tsweights` = `[['5', 61], ['6', 61], ['7', 61], ... ]`, then the function will return `61 + 61 + 61 + ...`.

Comment: I see, thats simpler then I thought

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Matt Ball's answer:

```
 var tsweights = [['5', 61], ['6', 61], ['7', 61], ... ]    
 , maxnum = tsweights.map(function(x){ return x[1] })
                     .reduce(function( p, c ){ return p+c })
```

as JavaScript doesn't have the sum function.

Or using new arrow functions from es:

```
 var tsweights =  [['5', 61], ['6', 61], ['7', 61], ... ]
   , maxnum = tsweights.map( x => x[1] ).reduce ( (p,c) => p+c )
```

Comment: More like the original Python, IMO, to use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: @MattBall yeah , you right!

Comment: Just wondering about reasons for downvote.